# Are there other "interactive" non-linear neural network layers besides self-attention layer?

Tags: neural-network, transformer, attention-mechanism

In the self-attention layer
$$
\operatorname{Attention}(Q, K, V)=\operatorname{softmax}\left(\frac{Q K^T}{\sqrt{d_k}}\right) V
$$
$Q$, $K$ and $V$ are all linear with respect to embedding vectors $x$, thus making the result a complicated non-linear function with respect to components of $x$. Because of the scalar product, the argument to softmax is a second degree polynomial $\sum a_{ij}x_ix_j$ mixing different $x$ components. As it is normally taught, neural networks contain strictly linear layers or non-linearities which act on a *single output* (ReLU, tanh etc). Are there other popular NN constructs which implement some form of highly non-linear functions which cross-mix the input components and what are they? If not, why?

Comment: LSTM's come to mimd.